# jQuery - Minus percentage from CSS pixel value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a bunch of `background-position-y` values from a number of elements and minus a percentage from the pixel value and then assign that new value to each element. E.g. Minus 30% of 40px = 28px. My code below is not working as expected.

```
var jq = jQuery;
var icon = jq('#weather i');
jq(icon).each(function(){
    var bgPosX = jq(this).css('background-position-x');
    var bgPosY = jq(this).css('background-position-y');
    var bgPosYNew = bgPosY - 30%;
    jq(this).css({
        'background-position-x' : bgPosX,
        'background-position-y' : bgPosYNew
    });
});
```

Comment: var bgPosYNew = bgPosY - (bgPosY * 0.3); ???

Comment: Multiplying by .7 is the same as subtracting 30%.

Comment: `var bgPosYNew = bgPosY * 0.7;` will be better ;)

Comment: @Kevin Labécot You're right - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the shortz:

```
jq(this).css('background-position-x','-=30%');
```

or as Klaus said:

```
jq(this).css('background-position-x','*=.7');
```

If you go DRY try this:

```
jQuery(this).css({backgroundPositionX:'*=.7', backgroundPositionY:'*=.7'});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I would have thought entering it within the inverted commas would have rendered that exactly as the value rather than perform the calculation.

Comment: The css-function `expression()` might be of your interrest too.

Answer (score 0):

var bgPosYNew = bgPosY - (bgPosY * 0.3);  this should work