# How to deduct 10px from dynamically calculated percentage margin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am adding some points to a div dynamically like

```
 var space = 7.14286;
 for (i = 0; i <13; i++) { 
    $('div').append('<span class="point"></span>');
  }
 $('.point').css('margin-left', (space+'%') );
```

while each point has :

```
.point{
      display:inline-block;
      width:20px;
      height:20px
}
```

I need to deduct `10px` from each margin to locate the .point exactly at the center? How can I dynamically deduct this or use the center of div as margin border?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Minus percentage from CSS pixel value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242895/jquery-minus-percentage-from-css-pixel-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use CSS [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) like so:

```
$('.point').css('margin-left', `calc(${space}% - 10px)`);
```